# Como haría este curl con el modulo requests?

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

Si mete este curl por el terminal me devuelve los datos pero en un script con request no me autentica, cual puede ser el problema?

```
curl -s -H "X-Auth-Token: $OS_TOKEN" \
  $OS_COMPUTE_API/flavors \
  | python -m json.tool
```

**código**

```py
user_token = args.token
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  user_token
}

# request url
req = {
    "flavors": "http://ip/v2.1/flavors",
    "images": "http://ip/v2.1/id-tenant/images"
}
# get account data
try:
    result = requests.get(req["images"], headers=headers)
    result_data = json.loads(result.content)
except Exception as e :
    print('0')
    sys.exit("\nError requesting %s, please check conectivity" %(req["images"],))
}
```

No me llega a autenticar, he probado también con :

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Auth-Token': user_token
}
```

Y tampoco nada, este es el error que me da

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openstack.py", line 243, in <module>
    desc = "Openstack image is  %s " %str(result_data['images']['minDisk'] ),
KeyError: 'images'
```

Comment: el ultimo error no parece que fuese error tuyo (al menos que no estés enviando un parámetro necesario)

Comment: no llega a cargar el json que me carga el curl, la cosa que meto el token por argumentos y es el mismo que el del curl, pero no me llega a autenticar, si pongo cualquier cosa como token me da el mismo error

Comment: Pero el traceback del error que sale al final ¿es de tu cliente o es del servidor? Por otro lado, en el ejemplo curl del principio solicitas la ruta `flavors`, mientras que en el codigo python parece que lo que pides es la ruta `images`, no son equivalentes, y sospecho que no está relacionado con el token de autorización, sino con la ruta o los parámetros.

Comment: haciendo el curl con la ruta de images me lo devuelve también, son diferentes request que quiero coger, no me pilla ninguna, yo creo que es por la url, porque si cambio el result data lo de images por error, me da error en minidisk (porque cuando no autentica en el json el primer diccionario es un error)

Comment: confirmado que es el token, con otro plugin que hice he probado poniendo cualquier cosa como token y da el mismo error y con el token bueno funciona, en este por lo que sea no logro que me autentique